# Stripe::InvalidRequestError: (Status 400) (Request) You must provide a `return_url` when confirming using automatic_payment_methods[enabled]=true.>

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I'm trying to store a previously Stored credit card using the Ruby API for Stripe.

here is my code

```
    pay_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
                                   amount: (invoice._amount_due*100).to_i,
                                   customer: account.stripe_id,
                                   currency: 'usd',
                                   payment_method: method.stripe_id,
                                   automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true},
                                 })

    begin
      Stripe::PaymentIntent.confirm(pay_intent.id)
    rescue StandardError => e
      #<Stripe::InvalidRequestError: (Status 400) (Request req_LQZggTPMa5j9Q8) You must provide a `return_url` when confirming using automatic_payment_methods[enabled]=true.>

      Rails.logger.debug e.message
    end

    pay_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve(pay_intent.id)

    if pay_intent.status == 'succeeded'
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create({ amount: invoice._amount_due,
                                       currency: 'usd',
                                       source: pay_intent,
                                       description: invoice.number })

      payment = Payment.find_or_create_by(acocunt: invoice.account,
                                          stripe_id: charge.id)


      payment.update({ amount: charge['amount'].to_f/100,
                       stripe_amount_captured:  charge['amount_captured'].to_f/100,
                       stripe_created:  payment.stripe_created || stripe_created,
                       stripe_currency:  charge['currency']
                     })

      AccountInvoicePaymentApplicator.new(invoice: invoice)
```

when it gets to `Stripe::PaymentIntent.confirm(pay_intent.id)` swallows an error. if I rescue from the swallow and examine the raised exception `e.message` I see that it is

```
      #<Stripe::InvalidRequestError: (Status 400) (Request req_LQZggTPMa5j9Q8) You must provide a `return_url` when confirming using automatic_payment_methods[enabled]=true.>
```

if I remove `Stripe::PaymentIntent.confirm(pay_intent.id)` and also remove the check for `pay_intent.status`, I get this error instead:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError: (Status 400) (Request req_SXriJ0MEQkjqiO) No such token:
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separated issues here and you can confirm it by looking at your Dashboard requests log https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs. ie.

1. https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_LQZggTPMa5j9Q8
2. https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_SXriJ0MEQkjqiO

The first error is pretty much as the error says: when using `automatic_payment_methods` you need to set the `return_url`. Since you already passed a Payment Method Id on the line `payment_method: method.stripe_id`, you should remove `automatic_payment_methods` on the next line.

The second error is because you can't create a Charge with [source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-source) points to a PaymentIntent. Charge is a legacy API and PaymentIntent is a replacement for Charge, why would you create a Charge after already having a PaymentIntent?

It looks like you are confused with your API usage and it's best to reach out to Stripe Support for clarification.